Macro with Parameter Fails When Trusted Locations Are Disabled
Error

I'm encountering an issue with a VBA macro in Excel. The macro works perfectly when trusted locations are enabled, but if I disable trusted locations, the macro stops working only if it has a parameter. Interestingly, if the macro does not have a parameter, it continues to work even with trusted locations disabled.
Here’s the code that causes the issue:
dropDownDisplayName = getShortDisplayNameForFact(factDisplayName)
Set curCombo = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddFormControl(xlDropDown, left:=Cells(6, newFactsCol).Left + 0.5, top:=Cells(6, newFactsCol).Top + 1, width:=width1, height:=height)
With curCombo
     .OnAction = "'AddAttribute """ & factDisplayName & """'"     
     .Placement = xlMoveAndSize     .Name = dropDownDisplayName     
     .AlternativeText = dropDownDisplayName
End With

In this code, the AddAttribute macro is not working when trusted locations are disabled.
However, if I create a wrapper function like this:
Function WrapperOFAddAttribute()
    Dim factDisplayName As String
    Set dropDown = ActiveSheet.DropDowns(Application.Caller)
    factDisplayName = dropDown.Name
    Call AddAttribute(factDisplayName)

End Function


and modify the .OnAction line to:
.OnAction = "WrapperOFAddAttribute"
the macro works even when trusted locations are disabled.
To summarize:

Macro without parameters: Works fine regardless of trusted locations being enabled or disabled.

Macro with parameters: Stops working when trusted locations are disabled.

Using a wrapper function: The macro works even with trusted locations disabled.


Could anyone help me understand why this is happening and suggest a solution?
why we need a wrapper to call the macro
